# how to properly pass literal strings python code to be excuted using python -c

Tags: python, string, cmd, literals

I need some help figuring out how to execute this python code from python -c
I am have trouble formatting python so that it will execute for another app in cmd
I understand there maybe other ways to do what I am doing but I am limited by the final execution using cmd python -c so please keep this in mind.

So I have some python code ie,

```
import os
import shutil

myPath =r"C:\dingdongz"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myPath):
    for file in files:
        os.remove(os.path(root, file))
    for dir in dirs:
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root,dir))
```

But I am trying to excute it using the following method, python -c "print 'hotdogs'"

So this what i have but no worky

```
cmdline = "\" import os, shutil \n for root, dirs, files in os.walk("+myPath+"):\n \t for file in files: \n \t \t os.remove(os.path.join(root, file)) \n \t for dir in dirs: \n \t\t shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, dir))" 

Windows CMD
python -c "+ cmdline +'"'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really really need to do a one line hack (this is totally not suggested or condoned) then you can do this

```
python -c "import os; import shutil; for root, dirs, files in os.walk('+myPath+'): for file in files: os.remove(os.path.join(root, file)); for dir in dirs: shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, dir))"
```

But what you should really do is make this a script that is inside your windows path, then you can do

```
python myfancyscript.py
```

Which seems a lot nicer right?

Comment: Thank you for replying but like I said above I'm limited by the final delivery of code. The python is being called by a server that does not have access to any python script I create, ie"myfancyscript.py" I try to run you solution above but I am still getting error tree(os.path.join(root, dir))
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

### Powershell guidelines for using python -c

- enclose the whole code section in `"` - so that you evaluate PowerShell special characters within (for newlines and tabs)
- use `'` for quotes within the code section
- use `` `n `` as line separators
- use `` `t `` as tab character essential for python indentation

#### Example: minify json oneliner

- that takes `foo.json` as an input and prints it minified version to the console

```
python -c "import json`nimport sys`nwith open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:`n`tprint(json.dumps(json.load(f), separators=(',',':')))" foo.json
```

- adopted from [Minifying JSON with Python · Jamie Tanna](https://www.jvt.me/posts/2019/11/23/minify-json-python/)