# Run python command directly on cmd in Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, command-line-interface

I am looking for a way, to invoke simple python one-liners directly from Windows cmd without the need to store a .py file somewhere.

Something like

`python print('Test')`.

Is this possible?

Comment: @Alex answer (below) pointed me to this resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048375/how-to-properly-pass-literal-strings-python-code-to-be-excuted-using-python-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use -c command line switch:

```
python -c "print('Test')"
```

Answer (score -1):

you could just type `python3` on your cmd and you'll get a sort of python debugger in which you can type and test your code.

so let's just type, `print('Test')` and it will execute

Comment: I know that, but that's not actually the question I'm having.